# Ideal gasses reaction under const temp and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, enthalpy

Conceptual problem:

> Let $A + 2B \rightarrow C + 2D$ be a reaction under constant pressure ($P$) and temperature ($T$), that goes all the way towards the products. $\ce{A,B,C,D}$ are ideal gases. Let $\Delta H$ be the molar enthalpy change in the reaction.
>
> What is the change in the internal energy?

The total amount of moles in the reaction is constant throughout it, can we say that $\Delta U=\alpha nR\Delta T$ is the term for the internal energy? (if so that will be 0).

Another idea is that $PV=nRT \rightarrow V=\textrm{const}$, and then the internal energy equals the sun of chemical work and heat which we know.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Got it!

as $H=U+PV$ and $PV = nRT=const$ we ger $\Delta(PV)=0 => \Delta U= \Delta H$